# Regex Match/Wildcard

Tags: c#, regex, text-files

I have a tab delimited text file containing comments/notes.

Any line that contains the the string "read" or "reading" will/should have an 8 digit number that I want to extract. The problem is I don't know where in the line the 8 digit number could be. As these are user generated comments each line could be different.

Example Line from text file:

```
3253442999934 did not read book # 98713429
```

what I have tried:

```
var m = Regex.Match(realLine, @".*""reading"":""\\b(?x)[0 - 9]{8}\\b$"".*");
var n = Regex.Match(realLine, @".*""read"":""\\b(?x)[0 - 9]{8}\\b$"".*");
//string pattern = "\b\d{8}\b$";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

    console.WriteLine((m.Groups[1].Value));
    console.WriteLine((n.Groups[1].Value));
```

I'm not generating any result, meaning nothing is printed to the console.

Comment: Use JSON.NET to parse JSON. And the spaces inside character classes are meaningful even if you use `(?x)` modifier. Replace  `[0 - 9]` with `[0-9]`

Comment: The file is a tab delimited text file. Not JSON

Comment: Then try `Regex.Match(realLine, @"\bread(?:ing)?\b.*?#\s*(\d+)")?.Groups[1].Value`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbread%28%3f%3aing%29%3f%5cb.*%3f%23%5cs*%28%5cd%2b%29&i=3253442999934+did+not+read+book+%23+98713429) (click the *Table* tab)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var result = Regex.Match(realLine, @"\bread(?:ing)?\b.*?#\s*(\d+)")?.Groups[1].Value;
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cbread%28%3F%3Aing%29%3F%5Cb.%2A%3F%23%5Cs%2A%28%5Cd%2B%29&i=3253442999934%20did%20not%20read%20book%20%23%2098713429)

**Regex details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `read(?:ing)?` - `read` or `reading`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than a newline char, as few as possible
- `#` - a `#` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.

To actually return Group 1 value, `Regex.Match(realLine, @"\bread(?:ing)?\b.*?#\s*(\d+)")?` is used, and if it does not match, an empty string will be returned, else, `.Groups[1].Value` of the current match object will be returned.